# how to send a Cursor instance from one fragment to a fragment which contains a recyclerview with same activity in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, filter, cursor, send

I am still doing my first steps with app development, so i would appreciate any kind of feedback for my code.
To my problem. I got two Fragments, "ListFragment.kt" and "SetListFilters.kt". My intention is to create a cursor instance in SetListFilters and then when I press a "apply"-button i perform a popBackStack while sending the cursor instance to ListFrament. To my understanding ListFragment will call OnCreateView() and there i want to pass the new cursor to my adapter so that the Recyclerview get filtered. I tried so many things but nothing worked for me. I hope you can help me. Here is my Code:

```
class SetListFilters(var transactionDB: SQLiteDatabase, var adapter: TransactionAdapter):Fragment(R.layout.fragment_set_list_filters), DataPassListener {

private lateinit var gridView           : GridView
private lateinit var btnYearFilter      : Button
private lateinit var btnMonthFilter     : Button
private lateinit var btnWeekFilter      : Button
private lateinit var btnRevenueFilter   : Button
private lateinit var btnExpeneseFilter  : Button
private lateinit var btnNeutralFilter   : Button
private lateinit var btnSbmtFilter      : Button
private lateinit var tvShowAmountFilter : TextView
private lateinit var sbAmountFilters    : SeekBar

private val viewModel: ListViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_set_list_filters, container, false)

    setUpViews(view)
    setUpButtonOnclick()
    setUpSeekbar()

    val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<CategoryEnum> = ArrayAdapter<CategoryEnum>(activity!!, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, CategoryEnum.values())

    gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

    // When the user clicks on the GridItem
    /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener { a, v, position, id ->
        val o: Any = gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)
    })*/


    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.filters.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { set ->
        // Update the selected filters UI
    }
}
fun onFilterSelected(filter: Filter) = viewModel.addFilter(filter)

fun onFilterDeselected(filter: Filter) = viewModel.removeFilter(filter)

private fun upDateQueryForDB(){

}

private fun getAllItemsNeu(): Cursor {
    val selArgs = arrayOf("r")
    return transactionDB!!.query(
            TransactionList.TransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            "type = ?",
            selArgs,
            null,
            null,
            TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_CREATEDAT + " DESC")
}

private fun setUpViews(view: View){
    gridView            = view.findViewById(R.id.gvCategoryFilter )
    btnExpeneseFilter   = view.findViewById(R.id.btnExpenseFilter)
    btnMonthFilter      = view.findViewById(R.id.btnMonthFilter)
    btnWeekFilter       = view.findViewById(R.id.btnWeekFilter)
    btnNeutralFilter    = view.findViewById(R.id.btnNeutralFilter)
    btnRevenueFilter    = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRevenueFilter)
    btnSbmtFilter       = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSbmtFilter)
    btnYearFilter       = view.findViewById(R.id.btnYearFilter)
    sbAmountFilters     = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar)
    tvShowAmountFilter  = view.findViewById(R.id.tvFilterAmount)
}

private fun setUpButtonOnclick(){
    btnExpeneseFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnExpeneseFilter) }
    btnMonthFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnMonthFilter) }
    btnWeekFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnWeekFilter) }
    btnNeutralFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnNeutralFilter) }
    btnRevenueFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnRevenueFilter) }
    btnYearFilter.setOnClickListener { changeButtonAppearance(btnYearFilter) }
    btnSbmtFilter.setOnClickListener{
        mainActivity.passDataCom(getAllItemsNeu())
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
}

private fun changeButtonAppearance(button:Button) {
    if(button.tag == "notPressed"){
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_select_button_pressed)
        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        button.tag = "pressed"
    }else{
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_select_button)
        button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!,R.color.mainBlue))
        button.tag  ="notPressed"
    }
}

private fun setUpSeekbar(){
    sbAmountFilters.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
            // Display the current progress of SeekBar
            tvShowAmountFilter.text = "< $i"
        }
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            // Do something
            //Toast.makeText(context!!,"start tracking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            // Do something
            //Toast.makeText(context!!,"stop tracking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if(tvShowAmountFilter.text.toString()=="< 0"){
                tvShowAmountFilter.text = "none"
            }
        }
    })
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    try{
        mCallback = (OnImageClickListener) //folled the tutorial, dont know what to replace it with
    }
}

}
```

---

```
class ListFragment:Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list) {

lateinit var transactionDB      : SQLiteDatabase
lateinit var adapter            : TransactionAdapter
private lateinit var filterBtn  : ImageButton
private lateinit var flActBtn   : FloatingActionButton
var mCursorFilter               : Cursor?    = null

private val viewModel: ListViewModel by activityViewModels()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val dbHelper = TransactionDBHelper(activity)
    transactionDB = dbHelper.writableDatabase

    adapter = TransactionAdapter(activity!!, getAllItems())

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.filteredList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
        //TODO
    }
}
private fun addRandomTransactionItem() {
    var a = 1234.56
    for (i in 0..10) {
        if(i%2==0){
        transactionDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO transactionList (type, amount, category, createdAt) VALUES('r', ${a}, 'K', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
        adapter.swapCursor(getAllItems())
        }else if(i%5==0){
            transactionDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO transactionList (type, amount, category, createdAt) VALUES('ne', ${a}, 'K', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
            adapter.swapCursor(getAllItems())
        }else if(i%6==0){
            transactionDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO transactionList (type, amount, category, createdAt) VALUES('ne', ${a}, 'K', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
            adapter.swapCursor(getAllItems())
        }else{
            transactionDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO transactionList (type, amount, category, createdAt) VALUES('e', ${a}, 'K', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
            adapter.swapCursor(getAllItems())
        }
    }
}

private fun getAllItems(): Cursor {
    return transactionDB!!.query(
            TransactionList.TransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_CREATEDAT + " DESC")
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
    val rvRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvRecyclerView)

    rvRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    if(mCursorFilter!=null){
        adapter.swapCursor(mCursorFilter!!)
    }
    rvRecyclerView.adapter = this.adapter

    rvRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(10))

    flActBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton)
    flActBtn.setOnClickListener {
        var ft:FragmentTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, AddItemFragment(transactionDB, adapter))
            ft.addToBackStack(null)
            ft.commit()
    }

    filterBtn=view.findViewById(R.id.ibFilterBtn)
    filterBtn.setOnClickListener {
        var ft:FragmentTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, SetListFilters(transactionDB, adapter))
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        ft.commit()
    }
    addRandomTransactionItem()
    return view
}
}
```

---

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

var mCursorFilters: Cursor? = null

private val viewModel: ItemViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewModel.selectedItem.observe(this, Observer { item ->
        // TODO
    })

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val listFragment = ListFragment()
    val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()

    setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        var ft: FragmentTransaction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.pageHome -> ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, homeFragment) // setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.pageList -> ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, listFragment) //setCurrentFragment(listFragment)
            R.id.pageProfile -> ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, profileFragment) //setCurrentFragment(profileFragment)
        }
        // ft.replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, AddItemFragment())
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        ft.commit()
        true
    }
}

private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.flFrameLayout, fragment)
        commit()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Typical strategy would be for the ViewModel to provide a SharedFlow or LiveData of the cursor. Remove the `getAllItems()` from your fragment, and instead subscribe to the flow or LiveData. The ViewModel would also provide a function for the filtering fragment to set what the filter is, and this function would make the new query and replace the Cursor in the Flow or LiveData. The first Fragment therefore doesn't have to know anything about making queries, changing cursors or changing filters. The second Fragment doesn't have to know anything about queries, just how to set a filter.

Comment: By the way, you can't have constructor arguments for a Fragment. It will cause a crash in any situation where the framework recreates the Fragment, like screen rotations or moving through the stack. You need to move your database property into your ViewModel. You can create a ViewModelFactory to pass the property through to the ViewModel constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to implement my viewmodel and passing the cursor. And also thanks for the tip regarding parameters in fragment constructors !!